# Inserting a node at the end of a linked list in c++ (walter/savitch)

Tags: c++, linked-list

This function is designed to insert a node after the tail node. This is just a practice problem from our book that I'm having difficulty with. There are the data() and link() functions that are designed to retrieve the node's info and next pointer respectively. The compiler is giving me an error on this line: cursor->set_link(i);

```
void list_tail_insert(node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
{
    assert (head_ptr != NULL);

    const node *temp = head_ptr;
    const node *cursor;

    node *i = new node; // this is the new tail pointer
    i->set_data(entry);
    i->set_link(NULL);

    if (!head_ptr) // if the linked list is empty
    {
        head_ptr = i; // the tail pointer is the new head pointer
    }

    for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor -> link())
    {
        cout << "Iterating to the tail pointer" << endl;
    }
    cursor->set_link(i);

}
```

Comment: At the end of the loop, `cursor == NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* problems.

The first is this:

```
if (!head_ptr) // if the linked list is empty
{
    head_ptr = i; // the tail pointer is the new head pointer
}
```

Here you assign to the `head_ptr` variable, but since variables are passed *by value*, which means they are copied, you are only changing the local copy of the variable. The variable you pass to the function from the caller will not be changed. For it to work you have to pass the head pointer *by reference*:

```
void list_tail_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
```

---

The second problem is that after your loop the variable `cursor` will be `NULL`. The loop condition should be e.g. `cursor->link() != NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely forgot about the second thing that it would be NULL. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm still getting an error with the "cursor -> set_link(i)" line. The error is  1 IntelliSense: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
            object type is: const main_savitch_5::node

Comment: @user3874530 It's because you declare `cursor` as a pointer to constant data, i.e. data you can't modify. To be able to call member functions on constant objects the functions needs to be marked `const` as well. But since you call `set_link` (which I assume modified the object) it makes no sense in making `cursor` point to a constant object.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL WORKING CODE:

```
void list_tail_insert(node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
{
    assert (head_ptr != NULL);

    node *cursor;

    node *i = new node; // this is the new tail pointer
    i->set_data(entry);
    i->set_link(NULL);

    if (!head_ptr) // if the linked list is empty
    {
        head_ptr = i; // the tail pointer is the new head pointer
    }

    for (cursor = head_ptr; (cursor -> link()) != NULL; cursor = cursor -> link())
    {
        cout << "Iterating to the tail pointer" << endl;
    }
    cursor->set_link(i);

}
```